# Why is this code throwing an ActionView::TemplateError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

I have some straight forward code that looks like the following in one of my erb templates:

```
if (<%= is_defined? foo %>) /* some javascript to do stuff with foo */
```

Is there a reason that code is throwing an ActionView::TemplateError exception saying `` `undefined local variable or method ``foo'? I thought is_defined?() should take care of that and not try to execute the code after utilizing foo if it isn't defined?

Answer (score 0):

it's because you not define the foo method or variable in your view. Define it. You not generate some javascript. You generate some ruby code.